# Ruby on Rails: Session with ActiveResource?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, session, client-server, session-cookies, activeresource

By default, ActiveResource client sends username/password in each http request to restful api. Can we configure it to interact using session id so that session is maintained between client and restful server.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe using the functionality from the 'Remember Me' part of the [this railscast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/274-remember-me-reset-password?view=asciicast) might do the job.